# Batch check for whitespace

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, whitespace

I want to name my batch logfile with the timestamp were it was created. But there is a problem if the time is < 10am. Then I get a whitespace and the filename will be corrupted. I tried to catch that via IF but somehow its not working and the cmd window is closing immediately:

```
set f_null=%time:~-11,1%
If /i %f_null% == " " (set zeitstempel_start=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,-5%%DATE:~-10,-8%0%time:~-10,1%%time:~-8,2%%time:~-5,2%) else
                      (set zeitstempel_start=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,-5%%DATE:~-10,-8%%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%%time:~-5,2%)

set startzeit=Start: %date% %time:~-11,2%:%time:~-8,2%:%time:~-5,2%
set datei_name=%zeitstempel_start%
echo %startzeit% > %def_log_dir%\%datei_name%.log
```

Any idea what  the problem is?

Comment: The entire problem could be avoided by parsing the output of `wmic os get localdatetime`, which doesn't contain a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set zeitstempel_start=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,-5%%DATE:~-10,-8%%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%%time:~-5,2%
set zeitstempel_start=%zeitstempel_start: =0%
```

replaces any <kbd>space</kbd> with `0`.

Your problem with the `if` is twofold:

1. `If /i %f_null% == " "` when `f_null` is <kbd>Space</kbd> is resolved as `If /i == " "` which is a syntax error. `If /i "%f_null%" == " "` work work - the comparison is very literal.
2. The sequence `) else (` must all be on the same line, not split across two as you have posted. It's possible (in fact common) to have `) else (` on its own separate line.

If you run the batch from the prompt, you could see the error messages that are being generated.

Comment: Thanks! But how could I search for a whitespace if needed?

Comment: That's a very broad question. The approach might depend on *why* you want to detect whitespace, and *where* the data is. For instance, to find out "does var contain a whitespace character?" you could use `if "%var%"=="%var: =_%" (echo no whitespace)`